# Uppercase of character present in all row

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am working on a data where few rows are with Uppercase character and few are lowercase.
I want to amend all the character in a row with Uppercase or with Lowercase, single amendment of a character is bit easy but I am not getting how to make changes in all columns.
I am using for ex.

```
attribset
attribset$Style[attribset$Style == 'sexy']= 'Sexy'
```

This only changes data with sexy to Sexy but I want to make changes together for cute, vintage, bohemian, casual, brief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attribset[] <- lapply(attribset, tolower)` will make all columns lowercase.

Comment: what if I want to make 1st letter of each word Capitalized in the same data set